# Remove the character at the end of the string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to remove the character ',' from the end of the below string.

**eg:**

```
v_rec(i).ACCOUNT_TYPE_NUM,v_rec(i).ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE,v_rec(i).ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,v_rec(i).INSERT_TMSTMP,
```

Could anyone pls suggest, how to perform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rtrim` as follows:

```
Select rtrim(your_column, ',') from your_table;
```

In PL/SQL, you can use `rtrim` the same way you use the normal function. (`v_rec(i).ACCOUNT_TYPE_NUM = rtrim(v_rec(i).ACCOUNT_TYPE_NUM,,',')` )

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is not clear because you are using fields from the loop variable. please mention your problem statement in detail with a small snippet